# How do I push tags back to a git repo using ruby-git?

Tags: ruby, git

```
git = Git.init("PATH_TO_REPO")
git.add_tag(tag,target,{:message => "tagged by RubyAutoDeployTest", :f => true})
git.push(remote = 'origin', branch = 'master', opts = {:f => true})
```

doesn't throw an error, but still doesn't push...
Additional info:
tag is an overwrite of an existing tag (moving it between commits).
the repo is cloned from a private github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force push tag, not a branch

```
 git.add_tag(tag,target, message: "tagged by RubyAutoDeployTest", f: true)
 git.push('origin', "refs/tags/#{tag}", f: true)
```

Comment: It gives me the following error:

/Users/gilz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/git-1.2.8/lib/git/lib.rb:764:in `command': git push '{:remote=>"origin", :branch=>"refs/tags/wa_prod", :opts=>{:f=>true}}' 'master'  2>&1:ssh: Could not resolve hostname {: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
 (Git::GitExecuteError)
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.

This is a repo I just cloned, so I have access rights and the SSH key is fine...

Comment: Sorry, my comment was inaccurate. I corrected params passing in `git.push` string. Try once again, please.